# How to create confirmed outgoing caller ID from Toll-free twilio numbers?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am trying to create outgoing caller ID dynamically.
But the problem is that Twilio does not create it because it fails to verify it (noone responds and inputs confirmation code).
Why do I need to verify number if I get it from the list of available phone numbers?
Can I emulate response which will send Twilio confirmation code when Twilio dials that number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Not sure what you mean by "from the list of available phone numbers".  Do you mean you've purchased a number from Twilio?  If thats the case you do not have to verify it, you can use any Twilio number as an outgoing caller ID.

If its not a Twilio number, today the only way to authorize an outgoing phone number is to have Twilio call that number and for someone to answer and enter the correct pin code.  The reason is to prevent fraud.

Hope that helps.

Comment: And can I use Toll-free number as outcoming?

Comment: Yes.  You can use a toll-free number as an outgoing caller ID.